What is this usage of ながら?
意識か、意識…。…兄貴は死んでるのか？
残念ながら。さすがに生霊じゃないな」
そう。…、我が兄ながらご冥福をお祈りいたします」
This is a back and forth between two brothers. The younger brother is talking to his older brother's spirit.
"Consciousness... so you are dead?"
"Unfortunately I am. I'm not a vengeful spirit."
I understand" 冥福をお祈りいたします is "Pray for happiness in the next life" but I'm not sure what to make of the fist part? For context the character wishing this is the younger brother.
From context I think it's something like "as your brother?"

I think you have the right idea. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/66601 is a different question but may help.

This ながら means "despite" or "although". It's the same ながら as in 残念ながら. Here, 我が兄ながら essentially means "Although it's odd to say this to my brother...". ご冥福をお祈りいたします is a formal expression and is not typically used within a family. Of course, the situation of saying this directly to the deceased is also highly unusual.
By the way, ご冥福をお祈りします is technically a Buddhism-origin expression, but it's also commonly used as a generic condolence expression that is not strongly tied to a specific religion, so you can simply understand it as "My prayers are with you" or "May you rest in peace". 生霊 in this context refers to the spirit that has separated from a living person's body (due to something like astral projection). By saying さすがに生霊じゃない, the older brother is indicating that he is not a living person's spirit but a "true" ghost.
