# What is これ the subject of in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

Dad has just given a useless answer to a question. Next we have:

> これが情けないことに、父ヒロシの答えなのだから、がっくりである。
> This, pathetically, is dad's answer, and it is disappointing.

Not sure if I'm parsing this correctly. On my first reading I tried to make これ the subject of 情けない but I couldn't make any sense out of it. The comma made me think that これが情けないことに was a single unit. If this is the case, how can I understand this construction? How does これが fit in?

I abandoned that line of thought and decided that これ actually went with the middle part of the sentence, i.e. これが父ヒロシの答えなのだ and that 情けないことに was more of a parenthetical comment. Is this the correct parsing? If so, why is the comma placed where it is? I know that commas don't really serve any grammatical purpose in Japanese but this one seems really misleading/confusing.

Comment: Do you understand what <adj>+ことに means?

Comment: @istrasci I thought that it effectively adds an 'ly' to the adjective e.g.　unfortunate -> unfortunately. And that it is used to express how someone feels about a situation.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61712/5010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right in that これが is the subject of 父ヒロシの答えなのだ.

情けないことに works as a sentence adverb that modifies the whole sentence. Generally this is the case with phrases ending in ことに. Some examples:

- 幸運なことにPS5を買うことができた Luckily I was able to buy PS5.
- 彼は残念なことに試験に落ちてしまった Unfortunately he failed the exam.

In terms of translation, *what is...* or *to be...* may be similar sometimes. (e.g. what was unfortunate.)

I guess a source of confusion is that in English you can use enclose such phrases with commas, but in Japanese doing the same is a little odd even if not impossible (i.e. in this case using "、情けないことに、").

Comment: It doesn't surprise me that putting commas either side of 情けないことに is weird, but if I had written this sentence I'd have put 情けないことに first, i.e.: 情けないことにこれが父ヒロシの答えなのだ. Would that be wrong? Would it have a different nuance to the original sentence?

Comment: @user3856370 You can put 情けないことに first. It sounds the same to me. Also, you can put it at the last (or as another one-phrase sentence) like これが父ヒロシの答えなのだ。情けないことに。 (The first "。" could be a "、".) But for the particular sentence (chibimaruko-chan?) it sounds overly literary. It sounds like deploring seriously.