# what does ことに...ことに... mean here?

Tags: grammar

> この教室の窓というのが、トットちゃんにとっては幸福な**ことに**、先生にとっては不幸な**ことに**、一階にあり、しかも通りは目の前だった。

I googled it ,and it only turned out  ことに used like this

> 残念なことに、その商品はもう販売中止になりました。

but this usage obviously don't match the context I provided

Answer (score 4):

The Google phrase you looked up is exactly what is happening here.
It sounds like トットちゃん is trying to escape the classroom.

This ことに attaches to some i-adjectives and na-adjectives and effectively adds the English suffix 'ly'.

In this case we have 幸福なことに = "happily" and 不幸なことに = "unhappily".

> This classroom window, happily for Totto and unhappily for the teacher, was on the first floor and looked out onto the street.

Comment: It's important to note that ことに always works as a sentence adverb (aka [disjunct](https://www.studysmarter.co.uk/explanations/english/discourse/disjuncts/)). English uses "-ly" words for both usages, but there's a strict distinction in Japanese. [This](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/61713/5010) is related.

Comment: thank you,your answer is accurate and concise