# Is this なことには here functions the same as 不思議なことには?

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation, phrases

> さらに重要なことには、これほどの美女がネズミを駆除するなど誰も信じない

i encountered this sentence on the witcher3 . Is this なことには here functions the same as 不思議なことには?

Comment: I think it's just a typo. Duplicated さらに重要 also seems strange.

Comment: というのは "さらに重要なこには" 正しい表現じゃありませんか

Comment: はい、そのままでは意味が取れないので、単に「ことには」の誤りだと思います。

Comment: で、この"重要なことには" は "不思議なことには" みたいな表現のですか

Comment: おそらくそれで合ってます。念のため書いておくと "more importantly," や "what's more important is that..." みたいな意味になります。 cf. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41108/57528

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ～ことに(は) can take various adjectives and works like English disjuncts.

- 意外なことに、…
  Unexpectedly, ...
- 驚いたことに、…
  驚くべきことに、…
  Surprisingly, ...
- 悲しいことに、…
  Sadly, ...
- 重要なことに、…
  Importantly, ...
- 興味深いことに、…
  Interestingly, ...

See also: [What's the difference between 意外にも and 意外に?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61712/5010)