# Ending a sentence with にな

Tags: anime, ending

Does it mean anything when a sentence ends with にな？

I've come across this several times, and have listed some examples below.

> - ああ ツイてねえこと**にな**
> - ヤツは扉を塞いだ 馬が通れない程度**にな**
> - まるで 最初からいなかったみたい**にな**
> - 生活のために 金品を借りて回ってたとき**にな**

It seems like the first one could be an abbreviation of になった, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Based on a quick googling, looks like 2) and 4) come from *Attack on Titan*.

Comment: Yeah, 1), 2), and 4) all do. 3) is from Cowboy Bebop (The Movie)

Answer (score 3):

This な is a masculine [filler particle meaning almost nothing](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/78059/5010). It could have been ね or さ depending on the speaker's way of speaking. Even if you explicitly translate it, it is no more than "you know" or "huh".

Therefore, you can ignore the な and interpret each sentence as a sentence ending with に. The に in those four sentences work slightly differently, but fundamentally, they adverbially modifiy something (e.g., the verb in the previous sentence).

> ああ ツイてねえ[ことに](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/101246/5010)。
> Yeah, unfortunately.
>
> ヤツは扉を塞いだ、馬が通れない程度に。
> He blocked the door enough that a horse couldn't pass through.
> <sup>(An inverted/倒置 version of ヤツは馬が通れない程度に扉を塞いだ)</sup>
>
> まるで 最初からいなかったみたいに。
> (It was) as if they were not there from the beginning!
> <sup>(See the previous sentence, there must be a verb that can follow this)</sup>
>
> 生活のために金品を借りて回ってたときに。
> (It happened) when I was going around borrowing money and goods for a living.

Answer (score 2):

It is rather に (the usual particle, typically meaning location) + [な](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%AA/#jn-162229), which is an ending particle that means:

> ３ 活用語の終止形、助詞に付く。
>
> ㋐**軽い断定・主張の意を表す**。「これは失敗だ—」

So virtually it means nothing. (You may have seen な used in an imperative, which is the same particle used in a different sense.) But usually な sounds masculine.

For the second one, it is in 倒置法 (rhetoric to add emphasis by inverting word order). In the standard order, it will be:

> ヤツは馬が通れない程度に塞いだ

(Note な must be dropped since it is an *ending* particle). The sentence moves 馬が通れない程度に to the last and adds な (for weak emphasis).

The others adds information to things previously spoken by the interlocutor. Translationwise, な can be understood as *And it was...*. E.g., *It is our bad luck (that ....)*